# can't get page source from selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, request

purpose: using selenium get entire page source.

problem: loaded page does not contain content, only JavaScript files and css files.

target site : https://www.warcraftlogs.com

test code(need 'pip install selenium'):

```py
from selenium import webdriver


driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.warcraftlogs.com/zone/rankings/29#boss=2512&metric=hps&difficulty=3&class=Priest&spec=Discipline")



pageSource = driver.page_source
fileToWrite = open("page_source.html", "w",encoding='utf-8')
fileToWrite.write(pageSource)
fileToWrite.close()
```

trythings--

1. try python request code, same result. that did't contain content only js,css things

It's a personal opinion, this site deliberated hide contant data.

i wanna do scriping this site data,

how can i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way of getting the page source, after all elements loaded:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time as t
[...]
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 5)
url='https://www.warcraftlogs.com/zone/rankings/29#boss=2512&metric=hps&difficulty=3&class=Priest&spec=Discipline'
driver.get(url)
stuffs = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, '//div[@class="top-100-details-number kill"]')))
t.sleep(5)
print(driver.page_source)
```

You can then write page source to file, etc. Selenium documentation: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/